# Can I enable the new Ubuntu/bash in Windows without installing the Insider Preview?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash

Microsoft has [announced that bash and Unbuntu will be coming to Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/). As far as I understand it I can wait for the Anniversary update this summer or install the Insider Preview of Windows 10 to be able to install the bash feature.

Is there a way to be able to install it right now in my non-preview version of Windows?

Comment: You cannot.  It only exists in the most recent build of the insider preview

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. If you put that in an answer and add a source link, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: This is a great candidate for you to provide the answer yourself.  The announcement, and all release material, was clear that this feature was only in the `Insider Preview` build which would be released after/during `Build 2016`.

Comment: It isn't clear to me from the blog post that it's coupled to the specific build - even with your kind pointers. This is why I asked the question (which at the moment has 1 down-vote / 10 views ;) ).

Comment: I don't understand how this statement in the blog post isn't clear.  "While we’re excited for you to try out this new technology, which will first become available in **Windows 10 “Insiders” builds after the Build conference**, we want to be clear about a few things:"  in other words the build has not been released.  There is a new Insider Preview .ISO which was released but, per their statements and due to the fact the build was released before Build even started that build isn't the build they are talking about.

Comment: Well, it could be interpreted as "which will *first* become available in Windows 10 “Insiders” builds" (but later by other means). But anyway, thanks for your help, and I will do as you have suggested.

Comment: Who would parse a complete sentence like that.  The noun in that sentence is `Windows 10 “Insiders” builds` the verb is `released` and the adverb is `after`.  `Insider Preview` and "Insiders" should be synonymous after a year and half of news articles on the Insider Preview program.

Answer (score 7):

I'm aware that this is a relatively old question, but it is a good one, and deserves an answer. This method will work on the *Windows 10 Creator's Update*, which is available to anyone, and not just insiders.

The official answer might be no, but there are round-a-bout methods that are actually built into the latest build of Windows. This solution involves using the developer tools option on Windows in order to obtain the Ubuntu on Bash application.

1. First, you'll need to enable the, "Windows Subsystem for Linux," as a feature. Go into the start menu, and search for `Turn Windows features on or off`. Once opened, you should get something like this
   [image].
   Go ahead an press the tick-box next to the Windows Subsystem for Linux option.
2. Second, you'll need to search `Check for Updates` in the start menu. On the left, you'll see a section named, "For developers," which allows you to enable developer mode. Select developer mode like so
   [image].
3. Third, type in `bash` in the start menu, and you'll see a command prompt window open. It'll prompt you to press Y/N, and because you want to install the Ubuntu subsystem (which is the only option that comes when you enable developer mode), press "Y," on your keyboard and proceed with the installation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "built into the latest build of Windows." Which latest build of Windows you are referring to? This is to prevent the answer become outdated in the future.

Comment: The question asks, “Can I install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in a version of Windows that is available in spring 2016, or do I need to wait for a summer 2016 version?” It is now summer 2017. Why do you believe that this question is still relevant? Have you actually answered the question? It looks like you have answered the question, “*How* do I install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in a version of Windows that is available in summer 2017?” That is not what this question is asking.

Comment: @Scott I would like to help out users that might be looking for a similar answer now. Plus, I stumbled upon this method sometime around 2016, and I've used it since.

Comment: @Vylix I've just updated this to be more specific. It uses the _Windows 10 Creator's Update_ build, but also works on versions beyond that build, I believe.

Comment: This is the only way I guess. else we have to go for insiders preview if you want to install from windows store.

Comment: FYI for anyone trying this, it required a reset for me after Step 2.
Thanks S. Walters!

Answer (score 1):

As @Ramhound has pointed out, the post I linked to includes the information that bash "will first become available in Windows 10 “Insiders” builds after the Build conference". So I guess that answers my question: No, there is no way to install bash in a non-preview build.